# Wrap an image in a padded div

Tags: css

Using a CMS, users of my site create posts containing images of various sizes. I'd like to wrap a container div around each image, but only with say 10px of padding on the left and right. That is, collapse the outer div's width to the width of the image + 20px. Is there an easy way to do this using css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNhRb/24/)

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500/500" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    float:left;  /*  or instead display:inline-block;  */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Mohsen. This was my thought initially, but the outer div seems to be filling the width of its container when I don't specify its width.

Comment: can you provide HTML ?

Comment: Sure. Wasn't positive on how to upload image thru jsfiddle, just think of inside div as image: http://jsfiddle.net/CNhRb/22/

Comment: I'll accept your answer because that solves the question I asked, but any idea if there's a way to do this without floating the container? This method doesn't allow users to right align images.

Comment: @Dave use `display: inline-block;`